# Is there an app similar to Pandora for movies/television?

Tags: webapp-rec, video, recommendations

I enjoy how Pandora can recommend new titles based off songs I already like. Is there a similar app that can take a few movies/shows I like and give me suggestions for similar ones?

EDIT: Showing the vids would be nice but what I'm really looking for is suggestions for other good flicks to watch, just the similar-theme aspect.

Comment: That's free? That would be uhm unlikely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fancast** http://Fancast.com is probably the best option for what you are looking for. Although that's not saying much. Here are a few other options as well:

**Jinni**: http://www.jinni.com/ was recommended by phwd as well.

**Get Glue** (as recommended by tsodermann below) does something similar to what you are looking for as well: http://getglue.com

**Hulu**: http://Hulu.com also offers recommendations after videos are complete.

**youTube**: As mention by phwd, http://www.youtube.com/disco is a good option if you are looking for more home grown options.

**Netflix** offers a suggestion feature based on things that you watch on their service. It takes into account movies and tv shows that you have watched online, as well as rented via their mail service.

You could sign up for a free account and take the preliminary survey if you really wanted to get a list of suggested videos/shows based on your likes/dislikes.

**IMDB** also has a chart of the top movies of all time, sortable by a number of different criteria, including, genre, decade, votes by their users, etc. View the list here: http://www.imdb.com/chart/top

If you are looking for "meme" type videos that you think you will enjoy, you could check out:

http://www.youshouldhaveseenthis.com/

http://www.todaysbigthing.com/

Comment: I believe that Jinni is most like what you are looking for - it also integrates with Netflix.

It is a fantastic webapp, I use it and would recommend it without hesitation :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Youtube Disco](http://www.youtube.com/disco) , a YouTube Experimental Feature, find songs similar to what you have just played and pushes in a queue.

The same rules apply to Youtube in terms of country restrictions.

[image]

Edit : **Now saw your edits**

The alternative : [Jinni](http://www.jinni.com)

> Jinni is a Taste Engine. We look at
>   film through the lens of what makes
>   you love or hate anything you watch.
>   With a Taste Engine, you don't search
>   by what you're looking for, you search
>   by what you like. And recommendations
>   are based on analyzing your
>   preferences, not statistics.

For Movies based mainly on rentals (Netflix, Amazon, iTunes) with the option of seeing online if available.

I am not sure how well the online option works tried it and got no results for common movies.

To get the recommendations engine up and running you will need to rate 10 movies.
In my case I rated 5 Jackie Chan Movies, 2 War Movies and 3 Spy Movies.

My recommendations ended up being a mashup of these categories. The more you rate the better the engine becomes at recommendations. You can even search depending on your mood, location or the type of plot.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [GetGlue](http://getglue.com/about) as well.

> GetGlue is an innovative social
>   recommendation network for movies,
>   books, and music. The GetGlue website
>   provides a recommendation stream based
>   on personal tastes, what friends like,
>   and what's most popular right now. The
>   GetGlue browser addon brings filtered
>   friend reviews, personal
>   recommendations, and contextual
>   content to popular sites around the
>   web, such as Wikipedia, Amazon, IMDB,
>   and hundreds more.

Answer (score 0):

I find that [Hulu](http://hulu.com) is pretty good for this.

You subscribe/rate/watch shows you like (even movies), and then go to Account > Recommendations to see recommended videos based on what you like. You can let it know if it was a good or bad recommendation so that in the future you will get better recommendations.

Here's [some information](http://www.hulu.com/discussions/18) about how the system works:

> We have updated our recommendation
>   algorithm recently. Basically, the new
>   algorithm will recommend shows which
>   you might like to watch based on your
>   behaviors: channel ratings, show
>   ratings, subscriptions, queue and your
>   watch history. The new algorithm is
>   based on item collaborative filtering,
>   that is, the more feedbacks or
>   behaviors you have, the better your
>   recommendation will be. Rating your
>   favorite shows as many as possible --
>   that is the most direct way that we
>   know your favorites and thus make
>   recommendations for you. However, the
>   recommendations based on connections
>   between items are not perfect due to
>   the shortcoming of machine algorithm.
>   If you find any bad recommendations
>   (i.e. if we recommend item B because
>   of item A, but you think A and B is
>   not related, etc), please use the
>   "feedback of recommendation reason" to
>   tell us so that we can gather your
>   feedback to keep improving our
>   service. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Rinema.com](http://www.rinema.com)

It gives you recommendations once you have rated about 20 films. Also, you can explore films by genre, language, tags etc.